# Multiples rows to columns with repeated rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I know that this subject is already well exposed here but I believe that I've a specific case and I didn't find any solutions so far.

I have the following result set:

```
Tp_Parameter    Value       Order_Id
------------    -----       --------    
Colour          Black       3824
Size            S           3824
Qty             2           3824
ItemId          101         3824
Colour          White       3824
Size            M           3824
Qty             1           3824
ItemId          102         3824
Colour          Red         3824
Size            L           3824
Qty             4           3824
ItemId          105         3824
```

And I'm looking for a result set like this:

```
Order_Id    ItemId  Colour  Size    Qty
--------    ------  ------  ----    ---
3824        101     Black   S       2
3824        102     White   M       1
3824        105     Red     L       4
```

I've tried with **pivot**, but I couldn't deal with the fact that it had to use aggregated functions, which one results in a one line result set (just the MAX or MIN etc etc)

Could you help me with that?

Comment: why 101 is Black, S , 2?

Comment: What is the relation between this values?

Comment: There is no logical connection between a particular `ItemId` and `Colour`.  The colour `Black` could belong to any of those ItemIds.  It looks like you're simply depending on the order they're currently displayed up there, but that won't work in a SQL table where the default ordering will be based upon clustered indexes.

Comment: You need at least one additional column to tie the rows together.  Is there at least an `id` on the rows?

Comment: table design is wrong in many ways.even from your point of view table design is wrong.

Comment: Sure thing, the design is very poor. I've no access to change/manage it on the source table (or even to suggest a better approach on it). I'm just trying to put in that way in order to "normalized" the results in a little bit more decent (but definitely not fancy) structure. Thank you very much guys. Thanks Gordon and @KumarHarsh.

Comment: guess you forgot mark it as answer,if it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this way too,

```
declare @t table(Tp_Parameter varchar(50)
,Value varchar(50),Order_Id int)

insert into @t VALUES

 ('Colour'   ,'Black',3824)
,('Size'   ,'S',3824)
,('Qty'   ,'2',3824)
,('ItemId'   ,'101',3824)
,('Colour'   ,'White',3824)
,('Size'   ,'M',3824)
,('Qty'   ,'1',3824)
,('ItemId'   ,'102',3824)
,('Colour'   ,'Red',3824)
,('Size'   ,'L',3824)
,('Qty'   ,'4',3824)
,('ItemId'   ,'105',3824)
;with CTE as
(
select *,ROW_NUMBER()over(order by (select NULL))rn
 from @t
 )
 select * 
 ,(select top 1 value from cte b 
 where tp_parameter='ItemId' and b.rn>=a.rn order by rn)MissingItemid
 from cte a

--now apply dynamic pivot so that you do not have to hard code parameter
```

Comment: yes, that pretty much worked for me. The key was the "ItemId" as a column (missingItemId). Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Let me assume that there is a unique, increasing id on each row.  Then we can say that a specific "ItemId" finishes the rows for the item.

If so:

```
select order_id,
       max(case when tp_parameter = 'ItemId' then value end) as ItemId,
       max(case when tp_parameter = 'Colour' then value end) as Colour,
       max(case when tp_parameter = 'Size' then value end) as Size,
       max(case when tp_parameter = 'Qty' then value end) as Qty
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when tp_parameter = 'ItemId' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by order_id order by <id> desc) as item_grp
      from t
     ) t
group by item_grp, order_id;
```